# Why does the Python installer keep popping up?

Tags: python, pycharm

[image: Screenshot of what actually happens]

Whenever I try to run the Python file, this window pops up automatically. Although, I can just close it, sometimes it opens up 7-10 windows back to back which is infuriating. Can anyone let me know why this is happening?

Comment: You appear to be using the installer .exe as if it were the Python interpreter. Install Python to somewhere first, then use the python.exe in the bin directory inside that.

Comment: Also, you should include PyCharm in your question so everyone instantly knows whether they are fit to help or not.