# Why is python setup popping up when I start Pycharm and where is my python interpreter?

Tags: python, installation, pycharm, interpreter

When I start Pycharm, this python setup menu pops up.

[image: ref1]

Python 3.7.4 is not even the version I'm using. Everything else works fine and I can just close it, but it is annoying.
There was a [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699169/why-does-the-python-installer-keep-popping-up), and the answer was

> You appear to be using the installer .exe as if it were the Python interpreter. Install Python to somewhere first, then use the python.exe in the bin directory inside that.

But I can't find where my bin directory is. My Python37-32 folder looks this.

[image: ref2]

How do I find my python interpreter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open some project -> File -> Settings -> Project: ... -> Project Interpreter -> Show All ... to view the list of available interpreters added to PyCharm.

[image]

Find and remove the interpreter which is pointing to Python *distributive* from the newly opened list.

At some point in past you added Python installer as a project interpreter in PyCharm so now when IDE tries to use this `exe` to run some background tasks (e.g. to get `sys.path`) installation wizard is triggered instead.

Correct `python.exe` to point PyCharm to is right on your screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#using-the-python-interpreter).

> The Python interpreter is usually installed as
> /usr/local/bin/python3.8 on those machines where it is available;
> putting /usr/local/bin in your Unix shell’s search path makes it
> possible to start it by typing the command:

Since you are using Windows here, you are already in the location where the python interpreter resides. So look no further.

By the looks of the screenshots, I have a concern whether you have installed python correctly.

If you did not select the checkbox for ***Add Python 3.7 to PATH***, the wizard expects you to do it manually which is why the error.

I would uninstall and reinstall Python and this time **make sure to check that box**. I am sure your error messages should go away.

Alternatively, if you're not in the disposition to uninstall. According to python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables) you can set the python variable to `PATH` variable and try.

Comment: I tried installing with PATH but it didn't work. One thing I realized is that 3.7.4 is not the version I'm using. Maybe something else is the problem?