# How to get rid of python modify setup pop up on windows 10

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

Few days ago I uninstalled and then reinstalled python due to some error related to pip . Since then whenever I start my pc it shows python modify setup window 2 or 3 times [you can see popup here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrsLv.png)

Though I can close these windows ; Whenever I open vs code it can be upwards of 10 pop-ups . What's bizarre about this is that I already have my VS Code set up properly . How do I prevent these annoying pop-ups?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall it completly since you got that pop up ? I encourage you to follow a tutorial while installing python to make sure you do it the right way. We don't really have enough informations about your system to help you further. Unless someone got exactly the same issue before, I doubt we can find a solution without more details.

Comment: Also I found this post which might be a solution for your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699169/why-does-the-python-installer-keep-popping-up

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you set python's installer as vscode's python interpreter.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> open the command palette and search for **Python:Select Interpreter**, select the correct interpreter.

[image]

***`python.exe`. instead of the python installer (such as `python-3.10.4-amd64.exe`)***

Answer (score 0):

**1. **Install python****

Get Windows Installer for python version you need from official
[site](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)

During installation pay attention to the "Customize install location"
[install location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGcnU.png)

**2. Select correct interpreteter**

Press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**Alt**</kbd>+<kbd>**S**</kbd> and go to -> **Project : *Project Name*** -> **Python Interpreter** -> **Add Interpreter** -> **System Intepreter** -> **...**

Choose python.exe file from installation directory

Now you're fine :D